# Hashing with mysql table data

Tags: mysql, arrays, hash

Im not sure how to perform the hashing in PHP. Im trying to do searching with text whereby this text will stored in mysql table.But i want the searching done with some hashing techniques where rather then searching using the WHERE clause to match the text it suppose to look for an ID and match the data which will faster.So i have an idea to sort and store this data in table in array and perform the hashing. But Im not sure about it. How to do this in PHP?

Assume i have table something like this

```
id   engineering    language
____ ______________ __________
1    chemical        malay
2    Electrical      english
```

Comment: If you merely want to improve the speed of lookups, just build appropriate indexes over your columns.

Comment: hi eggyal, can you please show me how to do this with some sample code.because i cant get how to do?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (engineering)` ?  You can append `USING HASH` if you absolutely want a hash index, but `BTREE` (the default) is probably more than adequate (and enables one to sort using the index too).

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE INDEX id_index ON table_name (engineering) USING BTREE;
```

compare BTREE & HASH

[refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)

Comment: hi sola, thanks for the feedback. .can you please give some example based on above table.whr can i edit this?
$query = "SELECT * FROM Engineering.searchkey ";
$results = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    // the query was successful; iterate through each result fetching an
    // associative array and add it to the `$results` list
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }    $result->free();
}$mysqli->close();
echo "try";
print $results;
// process all results in `$results` array!
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['ID'

Comment: actually INDEX has to create on the table in Database. It's nothing to do with query. Query will get execute based on the indexed column used in where condition.